# ReSharper breaks keyboard shortcuts for "Find" and "Find in Files"

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

I have been using ReSharper for some time and since I can remember every time I install Resharper, it's default keyboard shortcuts override Visual Studio's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for "Find" and "File in Files". It happend with R#3, 4, 5 in VS 2005, 2008 and 2010.

I don't have any ideas why would that be a good idea, but if this would bug it would be fixed by now.

Does this even happen to others? I checked around our company and I'm not alone.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same problem + slovenian keyboard...

Comment: Nope, there is no solution. It's only a problem with Slovenian (and probably some other) keyboard schemes. I fixed it by reassigning CTRL+F and other missing commands.

Comment: I'm another developer here on Slovenian with the same broken keyboard shortcut. David, did you report this as a bug to ReSharper team? I guess that this is a bug because it's apparently related to Slovenian keyboard layout and I suppose this is a kind of a bug that's hard to spot.

Comment: We have just encountered this problem with my colleague. 
We always reseted Visual Studio 2010 keyboard shortcuts to default and they applied Resharper 8 shortcuts mapping and Ctrl+F and Ctrl+Shift+F did not work. During this process, however, we had Czech keyboard activated. Then we switched to English keyboard and repeated the whole process again and this time Ctrl+F and Ctrl+Shift+F worked as expected. After this was completed the windows keyboard setting (English or Czech) did play any role any more and Ctrl+F and Ctrl+Shift+F worked as they should (Find and Replace)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I have the same problem with Serbian keyboard - which is the same as Slovenian.
Someone mentioned that the shortcut for the `GoToContainingDeclaration` feature that overrides 'Find' is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. Well, guess what - on our keyboards, `[` is typed as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Most likely that is why Resharper assigns the command that would normally go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Now the workaround (if not the solution):

- Reset the VS keyboard shortcuts (Tools>Options>Keyboard)
- Temporarily set US keyboard
- Set Resharper keyboard shortcuts (Resharper>Options>Keyboard&Menus)
- Go back to your keyboard of choice

Comment: Tnx! Didn't have to change to US keyboard though as this was already the case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. ReSharper seems to do some unorthodox keyboard handling and apparently fails with it. I use both hungarian and US layout and ReSharper sometimes "misses" the change between the two. In such cases, I can't type "[" (AltGr-F), instead it opens the ReSharper menu of VS. Can't repro it, though.

Comment: This answer really should be marked as the real answer here :-) . Second time that I needed it, second time wasted time looking at the marked answer, which is not much helpful :-) .

Comment: Oh. this is getting worse and worse. On Win8.1, I start VS2013 in US language, but when R# loads, it switches to Hungarian. I change it back and start the mentioned process, but when I try to set the R# keys, it switches back to Hungarian for a second, and finally I got the wrong setup... Grrr...

Comment: Yes, that's a funny behavior. R# opens new window with default keyboard settings and halts your attempt to set it in the prefered layout. :-) Setting US keyboard as the default keyboard for the moment helps.

Comment: Same thing happens for the Croatian keyboard.

Comment: I have a UK layout and this suddenly started happening. This sorted out the issue..

Comment: Applies to R# 10 as well, but at least no silent language switches happening in the backround now, like what @LukášLánský mentioned before.

Comment: You can see details and vote here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-346368

Comment: For the last several weeks, this solution needs to be enriched for a few extra steps.
Close the visual studio after every keyboard reset. Otherwise, it doesn't work for me anymore.

Comment: worked for me as wel. I have Resharper 2021.3 + VS 2022 Preview. Thanks

Answer (score 30):

as @cashmere said: Go to Open Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard.

In Show Commands containing  enter: `GoToContainingDeclaration`

Under shortcuts for the selected command you will see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Now you may change the shortcut or remove it.

Now you just need to check if `edit.find` command has assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> shortcut. Now it should work. At least it did for me.

Comment: Tnx, this finally solved my problem - tried 5 different proposals from this, and other pages. 

You can also remove Ctrl + Shift + F if you search for:

Resharper_SelectContainingDeclaration

Comment: ReSharper_SelectContainingDeclaration is the other, which overrides Shift+Ctrl+F

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this has just happened to me after a reinstall. I was using Vs2k8. Realised I didn't have resharper 4.5 installed. Closed VS, ran install, selected the same settings as I had been using for the last 8 months (VS settings) and then restarted VS. Now no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>! Very odd.

**UPDATE:** Well I found out what it was. The Find box had been relocated behind the Windows taskbar. I had to move the taskbar to the side of the screen, so that I could drag the find box back into the usable window space. No idea if this was a Resharper caused change but there was a direct correlation to the install.

Comment: I think there was a recent VS sp/kb fix that related to the find/replace dialog moving/resizing.

Comment: In my case (which is likely similar to OP's) is that shortcut just doesn't work. If you push those buttons, nothing happens. And if you go to *Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files* it opens as expected so it doesn't have anything to do with moved tool windows.

Answer (score 0):

Open Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and Press Reset for default keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Resharper - Options - Keyboard - Keyboard Scheme - None

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Gico answer. Problem is caused by GoToContainingDeclaration resharper feature.

1. Open VS Environment -> Keyboard
2. into field 'Show commands containing' type **GoToContainingDeclaration**
3. click on button **Remove**

This solved problem for me (I am using VS 2017).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No, never happened to me (I'm using Resharper 5).

If you check ReSharper's keymaps, you'll <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is not listed.

Comment: For me, it's listed as used by "ReSharper.Resharper_GotoContainingDeclaration (CTRL + F (Global))" and "ReSharper.Resharper_GotoContainingDeclaration (CTRL + F (Text Editor))". Could you check which shortcut is this command bound to on your system. That would shed some light on things. What language settings of OS are you on?

Comment: ReSharper.Resharper_GotoContainingDeclaration is bound to Ctrl+[ (Global) on my system. I chose VS keys for Resharper. 

System culture is set to Hebrew (Israel), but I don't think that this matter..

Comment: I would say the keyboard is the issue here. There is not [ key on Slovenian keyboard, that character can only be type with use of Alt Gr key. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @David: Just had the same problem. Another user with a Slovenian keyboard :)

Answer (score -1):

I've been using ReSharper since v2.5, and this never happened to me as well. Perhaps sometime ago the keys got mixed up. Try to reset your key bindings to default, and after that apply one of the ReSharper key schemes (VS or IDEA).

If this still happens, check maybe if your keyboard layout is that of US, or maybe something else...